# How to deploy reactJS app on docker with nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

hi everyone i am trying to deploy react app on docker with nginx server,
the dockerfile:

```
# stage1 as builder
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

# copy the package.json to install dependencies
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

# Install the dependencies and make the folder
RUN npm install && mkdir /react-ui && mv ./node_modules ./react-ui

WORKDIR /react-ui

COPY . .

# Build the project and copy the files
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:alpine

#!/bin/sh

COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy from the stahg 1
COPY --from=builder /react-ui/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 3000 80

ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

when i run `docker build . -t react-ui`
i got this:

```
+] Building 3.8s (15/15) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                              0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                               0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:10-alpine                                                                 3.4s 
 => [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                       0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                 0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 11.98kB                                                                                              0.1s 
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                             0.0s 
 => [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:10-alpine@sha256:dc98dac24efd4254f75976c40bce46944697a110d06ce7fa47e7268470cf2e28   0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] COPY ./.nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf                                                           0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 3/4] RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*                                                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /react-ui                                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 4/4] RUN npm install                                                                                          0.0s 
 => CACHED [stage-1 4/4] COPY --from=builder /react-ui/ /usr/share/nginx/html                                                     0.0s 
 => exporting to image                                                                                                            0.1s 
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => => writing image sha256:6f2eb618a9706c499387625528e0ba1803f4913ec13eaaaf27a4eca506c15dff                                      0.0s 
 => => naming to docker.io/library/react-ui                                                                                       0.0s 

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
51836b7e616378e20ecb21759c1f7703973178467aa3db5618ee3e3643e80ac0
PS C:\Users\Default.DESKTOP-LD6JUI4\Desktop\reactTT\ttfrontend> docker build . -t react-ui
[+] Building 85.8s (12/15)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                              0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 702B                                                                                              0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                   0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:10-alpine                                                                 1.9s 
 => [builder 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:10-alpine@sha256:dc98dac24efd4254f75976c40bce46944697a110d06ce7fa47e7268470cf2e28   0.0s 
 => [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                 0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 12.65kB                                                                                              0.1s 
 => CACHED [builder 2/6] COPY package.json package-lock.json ./                                                                   0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 3/6] RUN npm install && mkdir /react-ui && mv ./node_modules ./react-ui                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED [builder 4/6] WORKDIR /react-ui                                                                                        0.0s 
 => [builder 5/6] COPY . .                                                                                                        4.2s 
 => ERROR [builder 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                                                        79.5s 
------
 > [builder 6/6] RUN npm run build:
#14 1.008
#14 1.008 > ttfrontend@0.1.0 build /react-ui
#14 1.008 > react-scripts build
#14 1.008
#14 7.945 Creating an optimized production build...
#14 79.33 Failed to compile.
#14 79.33
#14 79.34 Module.createRequire is not a function
#14 79.34
#14 79.34
#14 79.40 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
#14 79.40 npm ERR! errno 1
#14 79.40 npm ERR! ttfrontend@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
#14 79.40 npm ERR! Exit status 1
#14 79.41 npm ERR!
#14 79.41 npm ERR! Failed at the ttfrontend@0.1.0 build script.
#14 79.41 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
#14 79.42
#14 79.42 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
#14 79.42 npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-05-22T12_54_09_630Z-debug.log
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

i think the problem with npm run build.

so please someone help me.
thank you

Comment: You seem to have attached a couple of image files to this question in place of the `Dockerfile` and the `docker build` output.  Can you [edit] the question to replace these images with the actual text of these things?  For example, I can't run a PNG-format Dockerfile to try to reproduce the issue locally.

Comment: David Maze Thank you for the reply, ok I edited it

Comment: You still have the build output as a png. Please change that as well. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: In your logs you have a `RUN npm run build` statement which you don't have in your Dockerfile. Please make sure that you're giving us correct information.

Comment: Hnas Kikian yes i do i just edit it , i am following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-serve-react-application-with-nginx-and-docker-9c51ac2c50ba)